# postgresql create view and save table name in new colum

Tags: postgresql, view

I´m just starting with views in Postgresql 9.1 and have following question.

Given are the following tables:

**pupils**

```
name  |  age
============
john     15
jack     16
```

**cars**

```
type | owner
============
volvo   1
vw      2
```

Is it possible to create a view that gives me this as result

```
ident | column
==============
john   pupils
jack   pupils
volvo  cars
vw     cars
```

My example might look a bit abstract but I´m in the the need to create one view from very different tables which all share one column which I´m interested in but except this have nothing in common.

My poor first step:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW test AS 
SELECT pupils.name, cars.type AS ident
FROM pupils,cats
```

thanks,

t book

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want a cartesian join between the two tables, you want a `UNION`

```
create or replace view test 
as
select name     as ident, 
       'pupils' as table_source
from pupils
union all
select type, 
       'cars'
FROM cars
union all
select cloud_number, 
       'clouds'
FROM clouds
select tree_name, 
       'trees'
FROM trees;
```

You can add any number of tables to this. The only restriction is that the common column must have a "compatible" data type (e.g. all `varchar`). If e.g. the 5th table has a `date` column that you want to include you need to add an explicit type case (or use a formatting function).

The column names of the result are determined by the column names of the first select in the union.

Alternatively you could also name them in the `create view` part

```
create or replace view (ident, some_column) test 
as
select ...
```

Comment: create thank you,this works. But how could I expand the select from pupils for more tables lets also a union with tables pupils,trees,clouds and cars?

Comment: @tBook Just add more `union all` branches. That isn't limited to two tables.